# El Capitan WiFi Connection Drops Continuously

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi

I have MBP Late 2013 and El Capitan 10.11.4 installed. But i have got a serious WiFi Connection dropping problem for a while. It is quite irritating as you may guess.

I couldn't find any clue why this is happening. None of my other devices experience the same problem, only MacBook Pro.

Here is the console logs
http://pastebin.com/fY3J5PUW

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

1. System Preferences – Energy Saver – Battery Power :
   Uncheck “wake for network access”
2. System Preferences – Network – Advance – TCP/IP :
   Configure IPv6 – Switch to “Link-Local only”

Found that above fix in the comments of this article http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/16/fix-wi-fi-problems-mac-os-x-el-capitan/

Comment: Actually setting wifi connection protocol to a fixed value (for example 802.11n) was helped me.

Comment: @bahadirarslan Glad to hear you got it working. Where can I set the  wifi connection protocol?

Comment: i configured it at router settings.

Comment: Ahh, was thinking it wasn't a mac setting!.Will try that if I have any issues in the future.